# To compute Euler’s pentagonal number theorem via dynamic programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, pow

Here is a [link](http://codepad.org/Ak9MdLY9) to the code and I have posted it below too.

```
 #include<math.h>
void pentagon(int n)
 {
    int k,p[10],a[10],b[10];
    if(n<0)
      p[n]=0;
    if(n==0)
      p[n]=1;
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
     {
        a[k]=((3*pow(k,2))-k)/2;
        b[k]=((3*pow(k,2))+k)/2;
     }
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
     {
       p[n]=pow(-1,k-1)(pentagon(n-a[k])+pentagon(n-b[k]));
     }
   cout<<p[n];
 }
 int main()
 {
   pentagon(4);
   return(0);
 }
```

I am getting the following error :
In function 'void pentagon(int)':
Line 11: error: call of overloaded 'pow(int&, int)' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors

Comment: Apart from this, you might also change line 16 to `p[n]=pow(-1,k-1)*(pentagon(n-a[k])+pentagon(n-b[k]));` (note the `*`) or something similar. Another error is that `pentagon` doesn't return anything (yet?), but you use it like a function returning an `int`.

Comment: http://codepad.org/7f663Q1C after changing.. Errors :cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int pentagon(int)':
Line 11: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 12: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 16: error: call of overloaded 'pow(int, int)' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

Comment: You may want to replace `pow(k,2)` with `(k * k)`.  Generally, fundamental arithmetic functions are faster than calling a more complex function.

Comment: Edited one: http://codepad.org/vm5d0Lr8 ......cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int pentagon(int)':
Line 11: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 12: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 16: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'

Comment: @Thomas ya true but but for the other loop, I will be needing it.

Comment: The expression `pow(-1, k-1)` seems strange. This is equivalent to `1/pow(-1, k)`. The denominator is either 1 or -1.  So why is the exponent negative?  This expression may be replaced by `(k % 2) ? -1 : 1`.  Did I miss something?

Comment: The array `p` is not needed and can be replaced by a single variable.  During recursion, none of the prior values are remembered; its like a new clean slate.  Also, `p[n]` is never referenced (on the right hand side) of any expressions (save for `cout`).  Thus it can be simplified to a single variable, `p`.  *Unless your function is coded incorrectly.*

Comment: @Thomas: No, `pow(-1, k-1)` is correct. It will return -1 for even, 1 for odd `k`. And I think using `p` as an array is correct for dynamic programming, but indeed doesn't make sense here (also see the output from my answer showing something's wrong). `p` should perhaps be global, but this doesn't help much either.

Comment: @All Thanks for helping. I got it but I am not sure whether I understood the eulers theorem properly. The question is as follows    :Another recurrence for p(n), which is a consequence of Euler’s pentagonal number theorem, is the following.
p(n) =0 if n < 0
;1  P if n = 0
;(−1)k−1(p(n − ak) + p(n − bk)) otherwise
where
ak =(3k^2 − k)/2 , bk =(3k^2 + k)/2

Use this recurrence to compute p(n) via dynamic programming with only a one-dimensional array. Where have I gone wrong in understanding the problem?

Comment: Sorry, but this function is bugging me.  In the last `for` loop, the index for `p` never changes.  You might as well simplify it so that it uses the last value of `k` in the iteration, which is `n`.  Substituting `n` for `k` leads to some interesting simplification, indicating that the prior `for` loop can also be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `2` with `2.0` as the second argument to `pow` (line 11, 12).

See also: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/pow/

Comment: Also, there's a call to pow in line 16 where it should be `pow(-1,(double)(k-1))` or `pow(-1,k-1.0)`.

Comment: Did that, still getting the error. cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int pentagon(int)':
Line 11: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 12: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 16: error: call of overloaded 'pow(int, int)' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
The modified code is http://codepad.org/7f663Q1C

Comment: Edited one: http://codepad.org/vm5d0Lr8 ......cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int pentagon(int)':
Line 11: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 12: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'
Line 16: warning: converting to 'int' from 'double'

Comment: See @schnaader's code snippet - it compiles without errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting and correcting all the errors (and warnings) leads to the following code ([codepad](http://codepad.org/ByxkCCuA)). I made some comments about what changed.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream> // Some compilers will complain if missing

using namespace std; // Some compilers will complain if missing

// returns int instead of being void
int pentagon(int n)
 {
    int k,p[10],a[10],b[10];
    // recursion end - we want to jump out here right away
    if(n<0) return 0;
    if(n==0) return 1;
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
     {
        a[k]=((3*(int)pow(k,2.0))-k)/2; // pow needs double as second argument
        b[k]=((3*(int)pow(k,2.0))+k)/2; //   and returns double
     }
    for(k=1;k<n;k++)
     {
       // pow casting and double as second argument, multiplication with pentagon
       p[n]=(int)pow(-1,k-1.0)*(pentagon(n-a[k])+pentagon(n-b[k]));
     }
   cout<<p[n]<<endl; // cleaner output
   return p[n]; // return the calculated value
 }
 int main()
 {
   pentagon(4);
   return(0);
 }
```

but I guess the underlying algorithm is still wrong, as the output is:

```
-1084535312
-1084535311
1074838088
0
3
4
0
```

Comment: It compiles perfectly. To get rid of the `cout` warnings I just had to include the usual `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Logical part I will see but I am still not getting even this.

Comment: @miku: Thanks, fixed it too, originally didn't because codepad didn't complain, but it's cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some errors or improvements I spotted:

Added iostream & using namespace std:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Changed `pow(k,2)` to k*k:

```
a[k]=((3*(k*k))-k)/2;
b[k]=((3*(k * k))+k)/2;
```

Add multiplication symbol to `p[n]` assignment:

```
p[n] = pow(-1.0,k-1) * (pentagon(n-a[k]) + pentagon(n-b[k]));
```

The `pentagon` method needs to return a value in order to use it in the above statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the **summation** part of the equation. 
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem.

Your `pentagon` function only calculates one term at a time.  There is no code that sums all of the terms.